# What is the purpose of this generic extension method?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm stuck on some legacy code here which i cant figure out. What does it do? Any help appreciated!

```
public static T ResolveNew<T>(this T type)
{
    return UnityContainerHandler.Create().Resolve<T>();
}
```

Comment: Try it out by writing `myEntity.ResolveNew()`.

Comment: That entirely depends on what `UnityContainerHandler` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code resolves the type `T` by capturing the statically known type of the object passed to it as the parameter. The object itself is ignored.

In other words, you can do this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
MyClass res = obj.ResolveNew();
```

This would invoke the extension `ResolveNew<MyClass>`, which in turn would return

```
UnityContainerHandler.Create().Resolve<MyClass>();
```

The utility of this approach is dubious at best, because the value of parameter `type` is dropped. Writing a different utility

```
public static T ResolveNew<T>() {
    return UnityContainerHandler.Create().Resolve<T>();
}
```

and calling it like this

```
var res = Util.ResolveNew<MyClass>(); // assuming Util is the name of the static class
```

would produce the same result without reducing readability.

Comment: Thanks man, made my day! :-D